# Delete all tags from a Git repository

Tags: git, git-tag

I want to delete all the tags from a Git repository. How can I do that?

Using `git tag -d tagname` delete the tag `tagname` locally, and using `git push --tags` I update the tags on the git provider.

I tried:

```
git tag -d *
```

But I see that `*` means the files from the current directory.

```
$ git tag -d *
error: tag 'file1' not found.
error: tag 'file2' not found.
...
```

Consider I have a lot of tags, and I want to delete them, all.

Answer (score 611, accepted):

```
git tag | xargs git tag -d
```

Simply follow the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) where you pipe everything.

On Windows use git bash with the same command.

Comment: Thanks. This command deletes the local tags. I used `git tag -l | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin` to delete them from the remote.

Comment: @CoDEmanX On Windows you should use git bash with the same command.

Comment: Doesn't delete remote tags, also very slow for thousands of tags.

Comment: @AdrianBaker Maybe you can increase the number after `-n` to parallelize. I'm not sure if this approach is safe though

Comment: and to delete a selection of tags (eg: all tags with v1.0.): ```git tag |grep v1.0. | xargs git tag -d```

Comment: To delete all BUT some tag, do `git tag | grep -v sometag | xargs git tag -d`

Comment: @CoDEmanX - for windows 10, just install the Windows Subsystem for Linux, type "wsl" and hit enter at a Command Prompt, and then you can use just about any bash command as it is.

Comment: 'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command on windows 10

Comment: git path must be configured in path for xargs to work

Comment: Don't forget to run `git fetch --all --tags --prune` before trying to delete the tags.

Comment: Run `git fetch --all --tags --prune` before if you get `fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs` when running the above code `git tag -l | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin`

Answer (score 335):

To delete remote tags (before deleting local tags) simply do:

```
git tag -l | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

and then delete the local copies:

```
git tag | xargs git tag -d
```

Comment: Remote delete is way too slow for dozens of tags.

Comment: This answer is way faster if you have a lot of remote tags: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34395864/747044

Comment: The order of commands in this answer assumes that there are no local-only tags.

Comment: This is too slow, below solution is better.

Comment: If you need to enter passphrase for commits, this requires passphrase for each tag. The other solution is better.

Comment: this solution requires passphrase for each tag which is laborious for big projects

Comment: after "cleaning" up the remote, how can my teammates clean up their local tags?

Comment: Removing the `-n 1` deletes all tags remotely in one fell swoop, which is way faster than deleting them individually. @ITGumby Use `git fetch --prune-tags`.

Answer (score 100):

It may be more efficient to push delete all the tags in one command. Especially if you have several hundred.

In a suitable non-windows shell, delete all remote tags:

```
git tag | xargs -L 1 | xargs git push origin --delete
```

Then delete all local tags:

```
git tag | xargs -L 1 | xargs git tag --delete
```

This should be OK as long as you don't have a `'` in your tag names. For that, the following commands should be OK.

```
git tag | xargs -I{} echo '"{}"' | tr \\n \\0 | xargs --null git push origin --delete
git tag | xargs -I{} echo '"{}"' | tr \\n \\0 | xargs --null git tag --delete
```

Other ways of taking a list of lines, wrapping them in quotes, making them a single line and then passing that line to a command probably exist. Considering this is the ultimate cat skinning environment and all.

Comment: I had several thousand tags, deleting them one by one from a remote cloud repo was taking days, which this solved.

Comment: What does the `xargs -L 1` do?

Comment: -L max-lines
--max-lines[=max-lines]
-l[max-lines]
Use at most max-lines non-blank input lines per command line. For ‘-l’, max-lines defaults to 1 if omitted. For ‘-L’, the argument is mandatory. Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line, for the purpose of counting the lines. Implies ‘-x’. The ‘-l’ form of this option is deprecated in favour of the POSIX-compliant ‘-L’ option.

https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html#xargs-options

Comment: @RichardAQuadling Ok, but what effect does that have in the answer? `git tag` returns the tags, one per line, and then `xargs -L 1` outputs them one per line, so what's it for?

Comment: Hmmm. Seemingly nothing in this context! Other than make things a touch slower!

Comment: Must have been having a very slow day. The `xargs -L 1` outputs 1 line of all the tags. So there is 1 line passed to the next `xargs` which is delete the tags.

So, rather than deleting 1 at a time, it deletes them all in 1 go.

I even wrote it out in English "... a list of lines, ..., making them a single line and then passing that line to a command ..." and didn't spot it when you asked about the `xargs -L 1`. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 50):

For Windows users using PowerShell:

```
git tag | foreach-object -process { git tag -d $_ }
```

This deletes all tags returned by `git tag` by executing `git tag -d` for each line returned.

Comment: `git tag | foreach-object -process { git tag -d $_ && git push --delete origin $_ }` if you also want to delete tags in remote. It will `git push --delete ...` each tag one by one, which can take some time if there are many tags. Does anyone know how to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Switch out `&&` with `|` if powershell gives you the error: "&& is not a valid statement separator in this version"

Answer (score 36):

If you don't have the tags in your local repo, you can delete remote tags without have to take it to your local repo.

```
git ls-remote --tags --refs origin | cut -f2 | xargs git push origin --delete
```

Don't forget to replace "origin" to your remote handler name.

Comment: Excellent! This deleted them all in one go. The other command was deleting one every 2 seconds

Answer (score 33):

Adding to Stefan's answer which was missing how to delete tags from remote.  For windows powershell you can run this to delete the remote tags first followed by the local tags.

```
git tag | foreach-object -process { git push origin --delete $_ }
git tag | foreach-object -process { git tag -d $_ }
```

Answer (score 18):

To delete all the local tags simply run the following command

```
git tag | xargs git tag -d
```

To delete remote tags after deleting the local tags by running the above command, you can run the comand below

```
git ls-remote --tags --refs origin | cut -f2 | xargs git push origin --delete
```

NOTE: replace origin with your remote handler

Comment: This one works best out of all the ones listed. The other ones return and error: `fatal: --delete doesn't make sense without any refs`

Answer (score 15):

For windows users:

This deletes all Local Tags by running git tag and feeding that list to git tag -d:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %a in ('git tag') DO git tag -d %a
```

(Found on: https://gist.github.com/RandomArray/fdaa427878952d9768b0)

Answer (score 11):

You can also use:

```
git tag -d $(git tag)
```

Comment: this won't work if you have a lot of tags, like thousands

Comment: in this case you could use something like:
git tag -d $(git tag | head -n 999) 
and execute it x times

Answer (score 8):

I have to delete the tags with prefix

for example, I have to delete the tags v0.0.1, v0.0.2, v0.0.3, v0.0.4, v0.0.5

```
git tag -d $(git tag -l "v0.0.*")
```

Decompose and explain the statement above:

1. To list all the tags with prefix

   git tag -l "v0.0.*"
2. To delete tags

   git tag -d $tag_names

That's how that statement works

Answer (score 3):

Since all these options only work in linux, here's the windows equivalent for anybody having to deal with that:

```
FOR /F usebackq %t IN (`git tag`) DO @git tag --delete %t
```

Answer (score 3):

Powershell v7 supports parallel foreach if you have lots of upstream (origin) tags that you need to delete:

```bsh
git tag | foreach-object -Parallel { 
git push origin --delete $_ 
git tag -d $_ 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recent version parallelized and filtered

```
git tag -l "v1.0.*" | xargs -L 1 | xargs git push origin --delete
git fetch origin --prune --prune-tags
```

First line, remove all matching tags from remote in parallel.
Second line, update the current repo by [pruning all deleted tags](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune-tags), from git version ***v2.26.2***.

To test the first line you can add `--dry-run`, I also encourage you to [explore the tag list command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---list), it has nice wildcards and exclusion/inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

For windows, doing this for removing remote tags:

```
git fetch --tags
git push origin --delete $(git tag -l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Show all tags containing "v"

```sh
git tag -l | grep v | xargs -n 1 sh -c 'echo "Processing tag $0\n" && git show -s $0'
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner that deletes both local and remote tags with a wild card pattern.

`TAGPATTERN="0.1.*" ; git push origin --delete $(git tag -l $TAGPATTERN) ; git tag -d $(git tag -l $TAGPATTERN)`

Remote tags are deleted first as the list is generated from local.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution anywhere that didn't requre a `git push` call per tag, so I came up with this variant, which - in my case - reduced the runtime from several hours to several seconds:

```bash
git push --delete origin $( git ls-remote --tags origin | awk '{print $2}' | grep -Ev "\^" | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Explanation

- `git push --delete origin $(...)`: Deletes a tag (or multiple) on origin
- `$( git ls-remote --tags origin | awk '{print $2}' | grep -Ev "\^" | tr '\n' ' ')`: Creates a space delimited string of all tags

  - `git ls-remote --tags origin`: Prints all tags on the remote origin
  - `... | awk '{print $2}' | ...`: Only prints the second column of the previous command output
  - `...  | grep -Ev "\^" | ...`: Filters out unwanted `refs/tags/mytag^{}` variants (not sure where they come from)
  - `... | tr '\n' ' '`: Converts the list into a space delimited string

It takes advantage of the fact that you can provide multiple tag names in a space delimited string, so it only invokes `git delete` once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use those command  lines to delete both local and remote tags.

```bash
#Delete local tags.
git tag -d $(git tag -l)
#Fetch remote tags.
git fetch
#Delete remote tags.
git push origin --delete $(git tag -l) # Pushing once should be faster than multiple times
#Delete local tags.
git tag -d $(git tag -l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Locally, git tags are just files on disk stored in `.git/refs/tags` subfolder.

You could just `cd .git/refs/tags` and remove all files stored there, with your favourite method of deleting files (`rm *`, delete from files explorer UI etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell you can just run this:

```
git tag | % {git tag -d $_}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).