# How to fix parsing go.mod module declares its path as "x" but was required as "y"

Tags: go

I am working on a go project, which has a dependency on `original-project`. I now want to change the behavior in this project by modifying `original-project`. So I cloned `github.com/y/original-project` to `github.com/x/my-version` and replaced all occurrence of `github.com/y/original-project` with `github.com/x/my-version` (including in `mod.go`).

But I keep getting this error:

```
go: github.com/x/my-version@v0.5.2: parsing go.mod:
    module declares its path as: github.com/y/original-project
            but was required as: github.com/x/my-version
```

Even when I run `go get -u -v -f all` or `github.com/x/my-version`

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You **cannot** reliably _fork_ a Go module or package. (There are simple case where this works, but in general it doesn't and cannot work). Remember: You cannot do a Github fork of Go code. There is basically just one possibilities: Make a hard fork producing a new and unrelated module/package, change that  and use that as the dependency of your code.

Comment: Modify your go.mod: module github.com/x/my-version, in your my-version project.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact that the `go.mod` of your cloned version of `original-project` still says `module github.com/y/original-project`. You should use the `go.mod` [`replace` directive](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive). It is meant for cases like yours exactly.

```
replace github.com/y/original-project => /path/to/x/my-version
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. What happens is that it replaces (stubs) the module on the module level, without creating a messy diff for every file using it.

Comment: To do this easily you can do this via the command line:
`go mod edit -replace="github.com/y/original=github.com/x/version@latest"` alternatively you can specify versions.

Answer (score 35):

I had similar issue. I ended up removing the go.mod file in the project I was trying to import and running `go mod init ...` again. It fixed it.

Also, run `go clean -modcache` where you are importing.

Then try to `go get ...` your package.

Comment: If you have an IDE, close it before going through this procedure. Instead of `go get...` , I successfully used `go mod tidy` - ending up with newer dependencies of course.

Comment: @malamut at the time I was using vscode + terminal, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: surprise, not working at all for forked project

Comment: I had to close the IDE before running the commands as @malamut pointed out.

Answer (score 13):

I'm currently developing a Go package and had this issue. I initially used the `module <package-name>` syntax at the top of my `go.mod` file. Since the module wasn't downloading correctly, I switched the syntax to be `module github.com/<user>/<package-name>`. Unfortunately, my system was still stuck on the old download cache, even after I manually deleted the dependencies.

To fix the issue, I created a new release tag on GitHub for the project (`v0.0.1-beta`), and now it downloads fine. `go get` stores modules with the version tag, so this bypassed the issue.

Comment: This worked for me and unblocked me. However I also had the replace directive in my go.mod but I am still needing to replace import paths even with the replace directive pointing to the new version

Comment: This is the only solution on this page that worked for me. Bumping the version tag on the newer project and then manually updating mod.go to point at the new package AND version allowed me to then run `go mod tidy` and `go mod vendor` (in my case) and everything auto correction. I did have to update the import paths, of course, but the replace directive would have avoided that.

Comment: @gregtzar I believe your problem was in Golang proxy server which keeps cache of downloaded package versions. You can try to set: 
export GOPROXY=direct 
to eliminate standard https://proxy.golang.org behavior

Answer (score 13):

The trick is to update the `go mod` cache.

So after making the required changes in `go.mod` (i.e. `github.com/X/Z => github.com/Y/Z`), you'll then need to pull down the latest version which will update your local `go mod` cache.

i.e. `go get github.com/Y/Z@fd02212`

and then the error message will go.

Comment: Thank you! `go get github.com/Y/Z@hash` forced it to download again and ignore the cache.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `go mod edit -replace` command.

Example 1:

`go mod edit -replace github.com/y/original-project=github.com/x/my-version@v0.5.2`

Example 2:

`go mod edit -replace github.com/codahale/hdrhistogram=github.com/HdrHistogram/hdrhistogram-go@v0.9.0`

From: https://github.com/HdrHistogram/hdrhistogram-go

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I didn't want to just fix on local, but be sure it worked for everyone.

After changing values in go.mod (it was better to delete the go.mod and go.sum files then run

```
go mod init github.com/organization/new-package-name
go mod tidy
go get github.com/organization/new-package-name
```

Above didn't really solve the problem for me, nor did `go clean -modcache`.

What worked for me instead was deleting then recreating the tags on the newly forked project. (suggestion: [Delete all tags from a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542301/delete-all-tags-from-a-git-repository))

Then create a new tag.

```
git tag v1.0.0 -m "new version"
git push origin v1.0.0
```

After this, you can just install via

```
go get github.com/organization/new-package-name@latest
```

OR

```
go get github.com/organization/new-package-name@v1.0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with the package name, after searching a lot I found golang cache coming from golang proxy server "don't know how" but cache store on my mac cleaned by running `go clean -modcache` but when i use `go mod download` or `go mod tidy` it always pick the wrong version package.

after rewriting `GOPROXY` variable to `GOPROXY="direct"` everything starts working.

```
go env -w GOPROXY="direct"
```

If it starts working you can revert your GOPROXY settings and using direct will show the module downloading.

If you using Goland then make sure you have enabled Go Module Integration in settings for Autocomplete indirect modules.

[image]

Comment: I've been thinking that there is some server that stores information about package name and path since cleaning cache doesn't work. And now your solution works I am getting more sure about it. Now I have another question: what if other person doesn't use direct, will he get the same problem?

Comment: @xekaiforce When there are multiple versions only then this issue comes, so if another person uses direct it may possible to get an error if the package is not updated to the cache server.

Comment: You can just run `GOPROXY=direct go get github.com/user/repo`

Answer (score 2):

The only way i found to fix this is try to find all occurrences of the old (and new, maybe) dependency and remove it manually

```
find ~/go | grep original-project
rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/y/original-project
rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/x/my-version
rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/y/original-project*
rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/github.com/x/my-version*
rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/sumdb/sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/y/original-project*
rm -rf ~/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/sumdb/sum.golang.org/lookup/github.com/x/my-version*
```

Then `go get` again

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was an issue with a `redis` library update from `github.com/go-redis/redis/v9` to `github.com/redis/go-redis/v9`

I had to

- update `import` directives across the application with a new library path
- update dependency declaration in `go.mod` file
- run `go mod tidy`

It helped me and I hope helps you.

Answer (score 1):

delete the go.mod and go.sum

```
go clean -modcache && go init
```

It worked for me

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to use code formatting. At the very least, `go clean` and `go init` should be on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Remove `go.mod` file from the directory
2. Run `go clean -modcache`
3. Run `go get`

Comment: This is not at all working, maybe in newer versions.

Comment: Agree with @Soumendra. Not gonna work this way.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I edited my `go.mod` and added:

```
require github.com/anyuser/anyrepo **latest**
```

Then, in the terminal, entered:

```
go mod download
```

Comment: Try to use [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) when telling someone to issue a command.

Answer (score 1):

Released tags are cached by golang here [proxy.golang.org](https://proxy.golang.org/). You might use `replace` on your project's go.mod but other people will have the same error. Either you use direct proxy as stated by @mandeep-gill or you can release a new tag after of the package source (if you are the author of course). People who used the old tag might still have the same problem they need to update to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

"Since Go 1.13, the go command by default downloads and authenticates modules using the [Go module mirror](https://proxy.golang.org/) and Go checksum database."
It can take a while, until those mirrors fetch your updated GitHub repository.

You can temporarily circumvent this behavior, if you tell Go that it should fetch the repo *directly* from the source:

```bash
GOPROXY=direct go get github.com/user/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was

Changing `module github.com/otherperson/therepo` -> `module github.com/me/therepo` in the `go.mod`

then running

```
go get github.com/myfork@latest_commit_hash
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did this and it worked.

```bash
go get -u "github.com/org/package@latest"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had the same error, I'm importing a private repo of mine from Github and the problem was that the name of the package ( first line in `go.mod` ) not the same name as the repo url. So we need to make sure that they are the same.

Error:

- Github repo url: `github.com/Mansouri147/private-repo`
- First line `go.mod`: `module mansouri147/different-name`

Success:

- Github repo url: `github.com/Mansouri147/private-repo`
- First line `go.mod`: `module github.com/Mansouri147/private-repo`

Answer (score 0):

i just input `go clean -modcache` and input `go mod tidy`, then solve.

Comment: Still get exactly the same problem as described in the question...

Comment: Fix bug in source code, not at `go.mod` .

Answer (score -1):

sometimes adding

> go get github.com/package-name@latest

also works,
considering you fork the repo and you have made some commit to it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35510082)