# Use fork of standard library to patch go/ast

Tags: go, goimports

I fixed a tiny bug in `go/ast` (see the following [Github issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/39753)). I would like to already use my fix in the project I am developing. The fork that contains the fix is available on https://github.com/ec-m/go.

First, I tried the following imports:

```
import "github.com/ec-m/go/src/go/ast"
```

and

```
import "github.com/ec-m/go"
```

which resulted in various `go get` errors like `module github.com/ec-m/go/src@upgrade found (v0.0.0-20200626183851-7b0f14cb18cb), but does not contain package github.com/ec-m/go/src/go`.

Then, I followed the regular approach of using forked dependencies outlined unter
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive
and also mentioned in various questions, f. ex. [How to fix parsing go.mod module declares its path as "x" but was required as "y"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311436/how-to-fix-parsing-go-mod-module-declares-its-path-as-x-but-was-required-as-y).

Specifically, I included the following replace command in my `go.mod`

```
replace go/ast => github.com/ec-m/go v0.0.0-20200626183851-7b0f14cb18cb
```

This and some other tries (`std` instead of `go/ast` etc) did not work. After some research, I found out that replacing the standard library of Go is not possible (see this [Github proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/35283)).

What other option do I have to use my fork of the standard library of Go? I would like the approach to be as simple as possible in order avoid dependency struggles for future users of my project.

Comment: After building  the compiler with make.bash you just use that go tool or set GOROOT. This has nothing to  do with modules or forks.

Comment: I don't want to build the go compiler, I just want to import my fork of `go/ast` into the project I am using, e.g. have an import `import go/ast` or something like `import github.com/ec-m/go/ast` that refers to my fork of the standard library instead of the regular one. I am sorry if my question is unclear, I will edit it and make it more specific.

Comment: @Volker I edited the question to make it clearer. Is it better to understand what I am aiming for now? I am quite new to Go so its possible that I have overlooked something trivial.

Comment: Or are you saying that in order for me to use a changed version of `go/ast`, I would always need to build the whole Go compiler? This would be quite terrible for anyone who wanted to use my project, so maybe there is a workaround somehow...

Comment: No. Nobody can use your patched version, only you can. But you do not need to build the compiler each time, once is enough (to bake in the forked GORROT) or you set GOROOT.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info - I compiled my fork and used it as the Go version for my project which worked!

Comment: Still not in Go as of 1.19, but issue merged into a proposal, which was accepted but not yet implemented... latest here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30241